# Why use different debug modules depending on production/development status?

Tags: node.js, logging, express

So the Express best practices page, among others, states that one should use the *debug* module for debugging and then something like *winston* for logging app activity in production.

- Why would one not use something like winston for all?
- ...and if using both how does one decide what goes in winston debug vs debug's debug?

[Express best practices](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html) / [debug module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) / [winston module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really not a big deal what library you use to log/debug, many Express applications use neither winston nor debug. debug just has some convenience features that makes it easier to use over using winston for debugging. You could certainly use winston, and write your own wrapper around its `debug()` method in order to replicate the exact functionality of the debug module. If you use both, just use the debug module to log messages used strictly for developing and diagnosing bugs, and use winston to log messages to a file/database/service while the application is in production.

Comment: "If you use both, just use the debug module to log messages used strictly for developing and diagnosing bugs, and use winston to log messages to a file/database/service while the application is in production" - But why? What makes winston a better module for production?

Comment: well at least winston has log levels and the support for different transports, not only the console output. You can easily log to a wide range of different other services including sns, email cassandra etc